# Server Side JS SDK fails to flag user

Tags: getstream-io

I have a webhook that runs on message save and message update.  I do some basic bad word filtering.  I can update the message to filter out bad words.  However, when I attempt to flag the message, I get an error.  Has anyone seen anything like this?  How have you worked around it?

The code:

```
client.flagMessage(message.id).then(r => console.log('flagged message', r))
```

I have verified that client works as I am able to update the message with client in the same Promise.all() call.

The error:

> Flag failed with error: "either user or user_id must be provided when using server side auth."

Version:
"stream-chat": "^1.7.4"

The docs:

- https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest/#flag
- https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/blob/master/src/client.js#L1227

It seems very similar to this closed issue:
https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/issues/113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a proper answer but definitely is a resolution for your problem.

If `setUser` is called on the client then server will be able to get the flagging user from the JWT (client side auth) but in server side auth, there is no user passed to server so you get the expected error message.

You check REST docs and as seen, server supports it where JS client lacks this server side support. This a missing feature bug from JS client. [It's reported to be extended as soon as possible](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-js/issues/314).